# How to make MSBuild use more threads when compiling multiple files?

Tags: msbuild, multiprocessing

I have an MSBuild file that I use to compile over 700 header files in a directory. It works perfectly except that it takes so long... I would like it to compile these files faster using multiple processes if possible.
Anyone have any ideas on how to do that, using this XML as a start?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >

<PropertyGroup>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <SDKFiles   Include="$(CompileDir)\**\*.h" 
            Exclude="$(CompileDir)\**\...;
                    ...
</ItemGroup>

<UsingTask TaskName="CL" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.x64.dll"   Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'" />
<UsingTask TaskName="CL" AssemblyFile="$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.Win32.dll" Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" />

<Target Name="CompileStuff">
...
    <!-- This CL.exe compiles all the files -->
    <CL Sources="@(SDKFiles)" CompileAs="CompileAsCpp" SuppressStartupBanner="true" ObjectFileName="$(IntDir)" WarningLevel="$(Warnings)" ExceptionHandling="Sync" />
    ...
</Target>
</Project>
```

I have tried the following, but with no success:
1. Passing in /m to MSBuild on the command line.
2. I tried some XML setting that specified multi-process's but it didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked how to make it use more process's instead of more threads.

Comment: If you start MSBuild with the /m parameter, it will use all processors that are available. But I think the CL task is slowing down your build. While we do not have C++ code here I never used the task, but the command line shows the parameter `/O2` to maximize speed. Maybe you could add this to the task, if not you could use the Exec task to directly call cl.exe

Comment: The /O2 parameter is not for build speed, but how the compiler optimizes the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since no one helped over these last 5 months, I may as well say that I had to write my own task extension. That task uses multiple threads to compile the files passed in.